# array_map - "Argument passed must be of the type array, string given" error

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-map

I am not sure why the following does not work. I get the above error (topic):

```
$array = array (); //something goes in here

function del_space(array $a){
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    preg_replace("/; +/", "", $value); 
    }
}

$no_space = array_map("del_space", $array);
```

Comment: What line? The error seems self-explanatory.

Comment: I pass it an array and it gives me the message that this is a string. I check that with is_array() one line above the code. This is a shortened version. This is taken from what I am writing in an IDE.

Comment: the array is empty?

Comment: https://eval.in/1020730 - Check it out.

Comment: If you are looking nospace in the array, just use the built function trim();

Comment: Post your *actual code* in your *actual question*. The code you linked to on eval.in has an additional statement that is the source of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `del_space` takes an array as the argument. `array_map` takes every element of the array (second argument) itself, and sends it to the callback (first argument). So unless if you have an array of arrays, this would not work. Your example should look like this:

```
$array = ['lblab; la'];

function del_space($a){
    return preg_replace("/; +/", "", $a); 
}

$no_space = array_map("del_space", $array);
print_r($no_space);
```

Gives output:

```
Array ( [0] => lblab;la)
```

If you want to pass an array of arrays, than the input should look like this:

```
$array = [
     ['blabla; bla'],
     ['blabla2; bla2'],
];

function del_space(array $a){
    foreach($a as $key => $value){
        $a[$key] = preg_replace("/; +/", "", $value); 
    }

    return $a;
}

$no_space = array_map("del_space", $array);
print_r($no_space);
```

With the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => blablabla ) [1] => Array ( [0] => blabla2bla2 ) )
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! This is the very first day when I write code, but after like 11 months of the theoretical edu. Thanks! How long to get better / feel the progress, if I can ask?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it working. It's hard to tell, I think with PHP it is relatively easy to learn the basics, but there is something to learn every day :) php.net is a great starting point, there is detailed description for every function with many examples.

Answer (score 2):

`array_map()` loops `$array` for you and since so I am assuming that each item inside of `$array` is not an array object but `del_space()` requires an array to be passed in to it.

It sounds like you have:

```
$array = array( 'some item' ); // Fails
```

but you need something like:

```
$array = array( array( 'some item' ) ); // Success
```

if you wish to use `array_map()`

Comment: Check out the eval.in url. It is an array and it does not work.

Comment: @gs3 I have a meeting, I'll check later.